# Who are some famous USSR/Russian Statistics/probability academic researchers?

Tags: probability, history

Who are some famous USSR/Russian Statistics/probability academic researchers?  Are russian (current Russia and former USSR) strong in this field academically?

Comment: "Famous" and "strong" are too vague and subjective to lead to a useful question for this site.  Please see our [faq] for guidance about what is appropriate and how to formulate a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to underestimate the contribution of [Andrey Kolmogorov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov), for putting probability theory on a rigorous mathematical footing during the Soviet era.

Also, [Andrey Markov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov), for his contribution to stochastic processes and Markov chains in particular, though most of his work was in the pre-Soviet era.

Possibly worth mentioning, though he was pre-Soviet Russia, [Pafnuty Chebyshev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev) for the Chebyshev inequality.

Answer (score 3):

[Vladimir Vapnik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Vapnik) - important contributions to computational learning theory (e.g. VC theory) and an inventor of the support vector machine.

Answer (score 3):

As @PSellaz mentions, Kolmogorov's contributions are very fundamental and include the standard axiomatization of the notion of probability (there are other ways to define a probability, but they aren't as well known as Kolmogorov's definition.) You might have also heard of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and Kolmogorov's 0-1 Theorem.  Due to his influence, there was a Soviet school of probability during the Soviet years. Some of Kolmogorov's students became well-known probability theorists. [Yakov Sinai](http://web.math.princeton.edu/facultypapers/Sinai/) (currently in Princeton) is one of them. [Yuri Prokhorov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Vasilevich_Prokhorov) and [Eugene Dynkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Dynkin) are two others. The American Mathematical Society has for many years translated the journal [Theory of Probability and Mathematical Statistics](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/tpms) from Russian into English. The list of editors and contributors should give you a good idea of who the current players are. To get an idea of how things were during Kolmogorov's time, look at Paul Halmos's book [I Want to Be a Mathematician.](http://books.google.com/books?ei=FjfgUKKdI8XL2QWPrIGQDA&id=F04PAQAAMAAJ&dq=I%20want%20to%20be%20a%20mathematician&q=Kolmogorov#search_anchor)

Answer (score 2):

USSR was strong in both probability and statistics, but after breakdown of USSR many of the most prominent scientists leaved Russia and have worked during a long term in Western Universities. However, some of them now work partially in Russia.

I don't say that I mention all of prominent statistics with deep connection with Russia, I just provide a list of people I encountered. Order is alphabetic.

- [Golubev](http://www.cmi.univ-mrs.fr/~golubev/) - now works on oracle inequalities for linear regression.
- [Shiryaev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Shiryaev) - one of the most widely known Russian scientists, disciple of the Kolmogorov probability school. He has prominent results in almost all probabily-related fields.
- [Spokoiny](http://www.wias-berlin.de/people/spokoiny/index.jsp) - now he is on the cutting edge of modern statistics, works mostly in Germany now.
- [Tsybakov](http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/~tsybakov/tsybakov.html) - well-known statistics with h index as large as 28 according to the Microsoft Academics search. I visited his lectures on sparsity in statistics. Works in France.